# Java: concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I am getting an error in the for(Entry...) loop where after calling dfs(), it will say concurrentmodificationexception. I don't know why it is happening even though visitedOrder is not related with the foreach loop. How can this be fixed?

```
public TreeMap<Integer, Integer> DFS()
{
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> stack = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> visitedOrder = stack;
    for(int i = 1; i < graph[0].length-1; i++)
    {
        stack.put(i, 0);
    }
    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> vertex : stack.entrySet())
    {
        if(vertex.getValue() == 0)
            dfs(vertex.getKey(), visitedOrder);
    }
    System.out.println(visitedOrder.values());
    return visitedOrder;
}

public void dfs(int vertex, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> visited)
{
    visited.put(vertex, order++);
    int currVertex = vertex;
    for(int i = vertex; i < graph[0].length-1;i++)
    {
        if(graph[vertex][i+1] == 1)
        {
            dfs(++currVertex, visited);
            break;
        }
        currVertex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your map is accessed by multiple threads and one of them modifies the map content (using `dfs` method) while other thread navigates through the contents of the map. In order to fix this, you can use a lock object to synchronize the code block.

Comment: I have 2 tree maps though. I thought that would fix it?

Comment: Not if both maps points to the same map object reference.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, thanks. At this moment of the day my brain shuts down and confuse the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Javadoc for "Class ConcurrentModificationException":

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify
>   a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general,
>   the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.
>   Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general
>   purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to
>   throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do
>   this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and
>   cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at
>   an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.

As it happens, that's precisely what you're doing: modifying the very structure you're using in your "foreach" loop.

WORKAROUND:

If you believe your design is correct, then substitute a simple for loop: `for (int i=0; i < myContainer.size(); i++) ...`

Comment: It's worth clarifying that your workaround is not a "fix" - a ConcurrentModificationException is a legitimate indicator that there's a potential issue with the code as written.  Sometimes it's fine to use this workaround and suppress this exception; however doing so without understanding why it occurred is a recipe for trouble down the road.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why it is happening even though visitedOrder is not
>   related with the foreach loop.

You are trying to modify the `TreeMap` while you are reading. 
You are just pointing the reference here in this line. So its just the same TreeMap with different reference name.

```
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> stack = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> visitedOrder = stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *just one* `TreeMap` instance that is created when you do a `new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>()`. The `stack` variable refers to this instance; the `visitedOrder` variable also refers the same instance. And when you call `dfs(int vertex, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> visited)`, the `visited` parameter also refers to the same `TreeMap` instance.

Now you're iterating over the entry set of this `TreeMap` instance in the `for(Entry<Integer,...` loop. While iterating, you call the `dfs(int, TreeMap<Interge, Integer>)` method and within this method, you invoke a `put` on the `TreeMap` instance and that modifies the instance; hence the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From the code you've provided, my understanding is that you are trying to convert a `graph` array to a `TreeMap` by doing a DFS. You are iterating over the `TreeMap` referenced by `stack` and trying to populate `visitedOrder`. To resolve the exception you are getting, just point the `visitedorder` variable to a `new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>()` instance.

Note that the fix I've suggested is aimed at fixing the exception while keeping you code flow and logic unchanged as I only have a limited picture of your solution.